# unresolved external symbol LNK2019 confusion

Tags: c++, lnk2019

stack overflow,

I have been trying to resolve my LNK2019 error with no success. I saw several similar posts on here so I gave this problem its due process and read the other posts (and tried to resolve it myself).  There might be something fundamentally wrong with my understanding so I appreciate your willingness to help.  I recently switched from python to C++, so excuse the n00bishness.

What I learned was that this error is often caused by compiling from different libraries - but I'm not sure how this could be the case for me.  If it matters, I am using the Stanford C++ library. Using VC++ 2008.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "lexicon.h"
#include "queue.h"
#include "simpio.h"
#include "vector.h"
#include "console.h"

using namespace std;
void findchoices(string &startword, string &endword);


int main(Lexicon &choices) {
    string startword = getLine("Enter start word (RETURN to quit): ");
    string endword = getLine("Enter end word (RETURN to quit): ");

    if (startword == "") return 0;
    if (endword == "") return 0;

    //cout<< startword << " " << endword << endl;

    findchoices(startword, endword);

    //foreach (string j in choices) {
    //  cout << j << endl;
    //}

    return 0;
}

void findchoices(string &startword, string &endword) {
    Lexicon english("EnglishWords.dat");
    Lexicon choices;

    foreach (string i in english) {if (i.length() == startword.size()) choices.add(i);}
    foreach (string i in choices) {cout<<i<<endl;}

}
```

That's it.

Errors:

```
1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl Main(void)" (?Main@@YAHXZ) referenced in function "int __cdecl Main(int,char * *)" (?Main@@YAHHPAPAD@Z)
1>G:\assign2-wordladder-randomwriter-PC\WordLadder\Debug\WordLadder.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: No, I don't think so.  vc++ 2008 express edition with nothing else I know about.

Comment: `foreach (string i in english)` is not native C++

Comment: Wow a 'custom defined main() as entry point.. So for an 'untrained eye' , a undecipherable, cryptic error message from compiler/linker and Well  C++ can turn into a nasty,  untamable beast if you don't tread carefully..

Comment: ya yikes I guess my code is a little sloppy.  I'm getting better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you defined `main` as `int main(Lexicon &choices)`? Change it to:

```
int main() {
    //...
}
```

Comment: @TylerSeymour Did it solve the problem? Honestly, your error message seems strange and I'm not sure about the answer.

Comment: Yes, solved it very elegantly.  My error vanished and it linked!  Thanks again.